# Adding one to all integers in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am completely unsure why this isn't working. I had it working a second ago but now I can no longer get it to function properly. Initially, I'm trying to add 1 or (num) to all integers within the array.

```
def my_array_modification_method!(i_want_pets, num)

    i_want_pets=["I", "want", 3, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 2 ]
    i_want_pets.map!{|i| i.is_a?(Integer) ? (i + num) : i;}

end
```

When I try and run this:

```
my_array_modification_method!(i_want_pets, 1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `i_want_pets' for #<Context:0x0000000174e6a8>
(repl):10:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this in the console, and I think you're misunderstanding how it works. With your current code:

```
def my_array_modification_method!(i_want_pets, num)

    i_want_pets=["I", "want", 3, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 2 ]
    i_want_pets.map!{|i| i.is_a?(Integer) ? (i + num) : i;}

end

my_array_modification_method!(i_want_pets, 1)
```

You're first defining a method `my_array_modification_method`, but **none of the code in it has been run yet**. Next, you call the method, with the arguments `i_want_pets` and `1`. Your problem is that `i_want_pets` hasn't been defined yet.

I think this is what you want. Define your method like this (the following all on Ruby 2.2.1):

```
def my_array_modification_method!(i_want_pets, num) 
    i_want_pets.map!{|i| i.is_a?(Integer) ? (i + num) : i;}
end
 => :my_array_modification_method!
```

Then make a variable later called whatever you want:

```
array_of_pet_things = ["I", "want", 3, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 2 ]
 => ["I", "want", 3, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 2]
```

Now, you can call the method you defined with `array_of_pet_things` as an argument:

```
my_array_modification_method!(array_of_pet_things, 1)
 => ["I", "want", 4, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 3]
```

Also, note that since your method uses `map!`, the original array `array_of_pet_things` will be modified:

```
array_of_pet_things
 => ["I", "want", 4, "pets", "but", "only", "have", 3]
```

Comment: I am aware of the destructive method '!' called on (.map!), and that it will permanently  change the array. That must have been my issue is that I had my variable defined within the method. I had moved it out earlier, tested it (it worked), then moved it back in (still worked). Because I didn't refresh though, I thought that it could work with having it within the method. >.<

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'd never given it much thought, but I think you're correct. Removed the IRB prompts, thank you for the tip!

Comment: Travis, For reasons I don't fully appreciate, some people just don't like to mutate objects. (Granted, it simplifies debugging.) On the plus side, changing an object in place tends to be much faster (and of course uses less memory) than making a copy.